# Automatically assign view model to every action in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to do this in a controller...

```
        protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        (filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase).Model = BindViewModel();

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

.... but Model has no setter.

My thinking is that my view (which is a form which when complete does a redirect) needs the same set of data to add to a drop down list whether its the first request or post backs. So I don't want to repeat the code for binding the drop down list data.

Any ideas? I'm trying to recreate a pattern I used with WebForms and list pages where I would leave my binding code until PreRender so no matter what action was taken earlier in the page life cycle, there'd be a fresh bind at the end of the page.

Comment: Why you don't want to use return View("MyView", BindViewModel())?

Comment: In post request ModelState preserve its state,so you dont need to set the drop down again.(Provided you are not clearing the modelstate).But Is it like you want to preserve the dropdown after redirect.

Comment: @EvgenyLevin That's what I'm doing now but its code duplication.

Comment: @Manas I'm not talking about the selected index. I'm talking about the list of items that are available for selection.

Comment: You use the same view for each actions?

Comment: 'Index', is what is first requested and then 'Update' is where the form is posted to. So yes...same view! I wouldn't want to duplicate the Html. I like to stick to one Controller per web page.

Comment: @Ian, If you are populating the dropdown out of Model properties like Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedIte,Model.ItemList) , Then the values will be preserved. But if you are constructing the dropdown list from some other parameters (out side the context of model) you need to repopulate every time.If the dropdown list is always same then you could put dropdown list alone as a partial view and use "OutputCache" attribute in the action returning the partial view

Comment: @Manas "If you are populating the dropdown out of Model properties like Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedIte,Model.ItemList) , Then the values will be preserved." How could the values be preserved when they're not posted back to the server?

Comment: @IanWarburton, Obviously you need to have it in hidden fields.I will try to explain in my post below.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question with an example (followed by a small explanation)

Lets define the Model as,

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropdownItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (Items == null)
                return null;
            return Items.Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i, Value = i });
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And in the controller,

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        model.Items = new List<string> { "A", "B" };

        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now in the view,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    <legend>TestModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedItem)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Items["+i+"]",Model.Items.ElementAt(i))
    }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedItem,Model.DropdownItems)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Explanation:

Model has a property of type IEnumerable Items ,which will populate the the property DropdownItems. In the view we can set the hidden fields for Items, so that it will be populated in each post request.So we need not set it again.

Comment: That's just like WebForms' viewstate. Thanks for taking the time to show me how to do that but its getting a bit off point isn't it? All that code and a bigger web request just to avoid writing 'View("MyView", BindViewModel())' twice!

Comment: Yes, Because HTTP is stateless each request should define its state.